# Prove using the binomial theorem

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-theorem

I have this homework question:

> Let $n$ be a positive integer, and $\alpha$ any nonnegative real
>   number. Use Binomial Theorem to show that $$(1+\alpha)^n\ge 1+n\alpha+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\alpha^2$$

I know that the binomial theorem states that $(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{n-k}\cdot y^{k}$. When applying this to the given expression I get $(1+\alpha)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\alpha+\binom{n}{2}\alpha^2+\binom{n}{3}\alpha^3+\cdots +\alpha^n$. I'm not sue how I can show that this is $\ge 1+n\alpha+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\alpha^2$. Thanks

Comment: Every term is non-negative. If $S=a+b$ and $b$ is non-negative, that means $S \geq a$.

Comment: Induction, as always.

Comment: @SinisterCutlass, we already proved it with induction. The teacher said to only use the binomial theorem.

Comment: This seems very similar to Bernouli's inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since every term is positive, 
$$
(1+\alpha)^n={n\choose 0}+{n\choose 1}\,\alpha+{n\choose 2}\,\alpha^2+\cdots
\\ \geq{n\choose 0}+{n\choose 1}\,\alpha+{n\choose 2}\,\alpha^2
\\=1+n\alpha+\frac{n(n-1)}2\,\alpha^2.
$$

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I didn't notice that... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There's almost nothing to prove.   $(1+\alpha)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\alpha+\binom{n}{2}\alpha^2+\binom{n}{3}\alpha^3+\cdots +\alpha^n = 1 + n\alpha +\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\alpha^2 + \binom{n}{3}\alpha^3+\cdots +\alpha^n >= 1 + n\alpha +\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\alpha^2 $

If n = 1 or 2 it's an equality.  If n > 2 it's an inequality.